# TextFormField resetting state on focus

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a screen which edits an item in a list. Users tap on the item and I pop the new page open which has a DropdownButton, a TextFormField, and a save button.

If you change the DropdownButton value first, then tap to focus on the TextFormField, any changes made to the DropdownButton value are reset.  The value returns to the initial state setwhen you navigated to this page, not the value the user has picked. How can I preserve the value the user picked here?

To open the edit page, I pass arguments from the list item being edited:

```
final updated = await Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => EditPage(
                              display: commute.display,
                              origin: commute.origin)));
```

The EditPage class itself:

```
class EditPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String display;
  String origin;

  EditPage({Key key, @required this.display, @required this.origin})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  EditPageState createState() => EditPageState();
}

class EditPageState extends State<EditPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Edit"),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            DropdownButton(
              value: widget.origin,
              onChanged: (value) {
                this.setState(() {
                  widget.origin = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              initialValue: widget.display,
              onSaved: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.display = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Save'),
              onPressed: () {
                final form = _formKey.currentState;
                if (form.validate()) {
                  form.save();
                  final thing =
                      Thing(display: widget.display, origin: widget.origin);
                  Navigator.pop(context, thing);
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to have TextEditingController for each TextFormField which will save the state of the text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the `Navigator`.  The broken code pushes a new copy of the `EditPage` instead of a fixed version.  Changing the code to this did the trick:

```
final editor = EditPage(
                 display: commute.display,
                 origin: commute.origin);

final updated = await Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => editor));
```